# Column level locking for read/update using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a admin table which stores the sequentially generated record numbers for different type of records.
Example :
Table: Admin
Columns:
DocketNextRecordNumber  of type number
ContractNextRecordNumber of type number

When the Docket or Contract record is created it basically generate Unique sequential record number
eg: DocketNextRecordNumber  = DocketNextRecordNumber   + 1

Problem here is When two Dockets records created at the same time they likely to have same Record Number. Basically here two different transaction, one of the transaction which commit at the end has the duplicate Record NUmber. Row locking for update lock entire row which is stop user creating record for Contract when row is actually locked for creating record for Docket. I need locking at the column level. Any suggestion how to achieve this using Entity Framework to solve this issue is much appreciated. Or any alternate approach also appreciated.

Comment: Search for Identity, Sequence, or if you want to do +1 Isolation level Serializable.

Comment: Using autoincrement for your key column would solve this problem.